# Samsung Xpress M2625D Prints Random Black Lines

Tags: drivers, printing, printer

I recently purchased a Samsung Xpress M2625D toner printer. After going through the process of setting up the printer and installing the driver on the provided CD, printing a test page yielded nothing but a page covered in black garbage lines. I restarted the computer and when that failed, installed a newer version of the driver from the Samsung website, but the printer is still just printing black lines. What did we do wrong?

Comment: Have you contacted Samsung? They would be in the best position to help you.

Comment: *"toner printer"* -- more commonly caller a "laser priner".  There are two ways to "print a test page".  The page can be generated by the PC or it can come from the printer itself.  Figure out how to generate a "local" print page or a selftest page.  If that is still "bad" then you'll know that the issue has nothing to do with the PC or the connection to the printer.  First guess is that there's an issue with the drum or toner cartridge.  Look for instructions on "cleaning" the corona wire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently we did not properly install the toner cartridge. Installing it properly seemed to take care of the problem.